# Terraform Backend S3 : Access denied in Codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to establish s3 backend for terraform inside codebuild project, But I am getting either

```
Error refreshing state: AccessDenied: Access Denied
151     status code: 403,
```

or `error configuring S3 Backend: IAM Role (arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxx:assumed-role/role-name) cannot be assumed.`

Here is backend configuration ( terraform file) which is uploaded as source artifact to codebuild.

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket       = "kcr-cs-bucket-xxxxxxxx-bucket-name"
    encrypt      = true
    key          = "terraform.tfstate"
    role_arn     = "arn:aws:sts::xxxxxx:role/role-name"
    session_name = "RoleSessionFromCodeBuild"
  }
}
```

Here is codebuild.yml

```
- echo "======== setting credential by env variables ========"
      - credentials=$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::${ACCOUNT_ID}:role/role-name --role-session-name "RoleSessionFromCodeBuild" | jq .Credentials)
      - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo ${credentials} | jq -r .AccessKeyId)
      - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo ${credentials} | jq -r .SecretAccessKey)
      - export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo ${credentials} | jq -r .SessionToken)
      - aws sts get-caller-identity
      - terraform init
```

Note: Before adding backend config aws command ran perfectly which means assume role does not have any problem.

I am looking for a way to provide credentials to s3 backend. In my view I dont need to explicitly provide since I have already set it as a env variable inside codebuild environment.

Update: After running `TF_LOG=trace terraform init`

```
Response s3/ListObjects 
400 ---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
401 HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
402 Connection: close

Response s3/GetObject Details:
400 ---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
401 HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
402 Connection: close
```

I have provided s3Full access managed policy to codebuild role, but does not able to read the bucket, do I need to provide explicit permissions to assumed role. Because I think assumed role does not have permissions to these buckets as assumed role is from other account? Could that be so?

Comment: What user/role is running the terraform code? Sounds like it doesn't have permission to assume the role arn you put in the backend config

Comment: Remove the role_arn from the terraform config if you already provide the assumed credentials. Or remove the assume role outside of it.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle role is having permissions because `aws s3 ls` command worked before setting up the backend config.

@luk2302 after removing the role arn now I only 403 access denied.

Comment: But most likely somewhere different? E.g. when deploying the actual resources, not the backend config!?

Comment: Can you provide an example.